# iOS Facebook graph API send status image URL

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Actually, I use this code:

```
NSMutableDictionary* params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[params setObject:@"message" forKey:@"message"];
[params setObject:@"status" forKey:@"type"];
[params setObject:@"name" forKey:@"name"];
[params setObject:@"caption" forKey:@"caption"];
[params setObject:@"description" forKey:@"description"];
[params setObject:@"http://www.domain.de/picture.png" forKey:@"picture"];
```

This works, but the name now link to the picture-URL.

How can I link to the domain without using the key "link", because I like to post a status message, not a link (like in the app runtastic)

Thanks,

Christian